# represent this range (11.4-12.6) in regex?

Tags: regex

How can I represent this range (11.4-12.6) in regex?
I need to approve values => 11.4 and < 12.6

Thanks

Comment: Are zero prefixes allowed? And how about scientific form like 1.14e1 or 0.126e2?

Comment: `/11.[4-9]|12(\.[0-6])/`

Comment: (11\.[4-9]|12\.[0-6])

Comment: Why regex? Why not check it as a number?

Comment: `/11.[4-9]|12(\.[0-6])?/`

Comment: That'll work thanks, will just need to change the range to [0-6] but how can I represent ranges in general? how would I represent the following for example:
value greater or equal to 1000 and less than 5500
OR
value greater or equal to 0 and less than 10.8

Comment: Regular Expression is not a tool to do this kind of validation. You should not use it for that task. You should use it to validate if the input is right then check the value as numbers.

Comment: ^(11.[4-9]|12(\.[0-5])?)$ is the answer.
Thanks a lot for your help
it passes values greater or equal to 11.4 and less than 12.6

Comment: @Perla why do you only escape the second dot?

Answer (score 0):

`^(11\.[4-9]|12\.[0-6])`

Matches:

```
11.4
11.5
11.6
11.7
11.8
11.9
12.0
12.1
12.2
12.3
12.4
12.5
12.6
```

https://regex101.com/r/sC6vG4/1

Comment: And it matches `111.4`.

Comment: Updated to use `^`